# Visual Studio 2015 loop performance degradation when storing pointers in struct

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I found that the following loop

```
std::vector<int> x,y,z;
...
unsigned int res=0;
auto p=x.data();
auto q=y.data();
auto r=z.data();
for(unsigned int i=0;i<N;++i){
  res+=*p++ +*q++ +*r++;
}
```

runs almost twice as fast as this one, which merely packs the pointers in a struct:

```
struct pdata{int *px,*py,*pz;};

unsigned int res=0;
pdata d{x.data(),y.data(),z.data()};
for(unsigned int i=0;i<N;++i){
  res+=*d.px++ +*d.py++ +*d.pz++;
}
return res;
```

Is this a known performance issue? Please find below complete program and performance measurements for Visual C++ 2015 in 32-bit (x86) release mode (default settings), Windows 7 64-bit, Intel Core i5-2520M @2.5GHz:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric> 

std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point measure_start,measure_pause;

template<typename F>
double measure(F f)
{
  using namespace std::chrono;

  static const int              num_trials=10;
  static const milliseconds     min_time_per_trial(200);
  std::array<double,num_trials> trials;
  volatile decltype(f())        res; /* to avoid optimizing f() away */

  for(int i=0;i<num_trials;++i){
    int                               runs=0;
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2;

    measure_start=high_resolution_clock::now();
    do{
      res=f();
      ++runs;
      t2=high_resolution_clock::now();
    }while(t2-measure_start<min_time_per_trial);
    trials[i]=duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2-measure_start).count()/runs;
  }
  (void)res; /* var not used warn */

  std::sort(trials.begin(),trials.end());
  return std::accumulate(
    trials.begin()+2,trials.end()-2,0.0)/(trials.size()-4);
}

template<typename F>
double measure(unsigned int n,F f)
{
  double t=measure(f);
  return (t/n)*10E9;
}    

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  static const unsigned int N=100000;
  std::vector<int> x(N),y(N),z(N);

  for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    x[i]=i;
    y[i]=i+1;
    z[i]=i+2;
  }

  std::cout<<measure(N,[&]{
    unsigned int res=0;
    auto p=x.data();
    auto q=y.data();
    auto r=z.data();
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<N;++i){
      res+=*p++ +*q++ +*r++;
    }
    return res;
  })<<",";

  std::cout<<measure(N,[&]{
    struct pdata{int *px,*py,*pz;};

    unsigned int res=0;
    pdata d{x.data(),y.data(),z.data()};
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<N;++i){
      res+=*d.px++ +*d.py++ +*d.pz++;
    }
    return res;
  })<<"\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
4.24541,7.44588
```

Thank you,

Comment: If you ever put code like `res+=*d.px+++*d.py+++*d.pz++;` into any codebase I have any control over; I'm going to do something really unpleasant to you.

Comment: [The assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/LGWjbr) generated from your examples is fairly interesting.  MSVC seems smart enough to do some significant optimization of the first example _sometimes_.  Other times not so much.  The second example never seems to get the same optimizations applied.

Comment: @Miles Budnek who cares? Nobody should write obfuscated code like this in the first place. Not even if it saves a few nanoseconds.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Oh, I'm not saying it's clean or good code.  Just that the assembly is somewhat interesting.  Indeed, the obfuscation is likely what's _preventing_ the compiler from realizing that the second example is simple iteration over three vectors and applying the same optimizations as the first case.

Comment: I didn't mind that line. Wouldn't put it in production code, I guess, but it's pretty obvious what it does.

Comment: this is fine `res += *d.px++ + *d.py++ + *d.pz++` and the fact that the machine code that gets generate is totally different (and hence takes twice as long in the second case) is interesting

Answer (score 1):

Fascinating. This seems to be indeed a performance/optimization issue.
Loop #1 uses MMX opcodes:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
res += *p++ + *q++ + *r++;
00C812C0  lea         eax,[eax+20h]  
00C812C3  lea         esi,[esi+20h]  
00C812C6  lea         edx,[edx+20h]  
00C812C9  movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [esi-20h]  
00C812CD  movups      xmm1,xmmword ptr [eax-20h]  
00C812D1  paddd       xmm1,xmm0  
00C812D5  movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [edx-20h]  
00C812D9  paddd       xmm1,xmm0  
00C812DD  paddd       xmm3,xmm1  
00C812E1  movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [esi-10h]  
00C812E5  movups      xmm1,xmmword ptr [eax-10h]  
00C812E9  paddd       xmm1,xmm0  
00C812ED  movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [edx-10h]  
00C812F1  paddd       xmm1,xmm0  
00C812F5  paddd       xmm2,xmm1  
00C812F9  sub         ecx,1  
00C812FC  jne
```

while Loop #2 uses standard opcodes:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
res += *d.px++ + *d.py++ + *d.pz++;
00C81340  mov         eax,dword ptr [edi]  
00C81342  lea         ecx,[ecx+14h]  
00C81345  add         eax,dword ptr [esi]  
00C81347  lea         edi,[edi+14h]  
00C8134A  add         eax,dword ptr [ecx-14h]  
00C8134D  lea         esi,[esi+14h]  
00C81350  mov         edx,dword ptr [edi-4]  
00C81353  add         ebx,eax  
00C81355  mov         eax,dword ptr [edi-10h]  
00C81358  add         eax,dword ptr [esi-10h]  
00C8135B  add         eax,dword ptr [ecx-10h]  
00C8135E  add         edx,dword ptr [esi-4]  
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
res += *d.px++ + *d.py++ + *d.pz++;
00C81361  add         ebx,eax  
00C81363  mov         eax,dword ptr [edi-0Ch]  
00C81366  add         eax,dword ptr [esi-0Ch]  
00C81369  add         eax,dword ptr [ecx-0Ch]  
00C8136C  add         edx,dword ptr [ecx-4]  
00C8136F  add         ebx,eax  
00C81371  mov         eax,dword ptr [edi-8]  
00C81374  add         eax,dword ptr [esi-8]  
00C81377  add         eax,dword ptr [ecx-8]  
00C8137A  add         ebx,eax  
00C8137C  add         ebx,edx  
00C8137E  sub         dword ptr [ebp-4],1  
00C81382  jne         <lambda_90dad2b8e1a29d982a00cc5b5b0ef516>::operator()+20h (0C81340h)
```

I have next to no knowledge about X86/MMX assembler, but obviously the MMX stuff is much faster.
I don't know why it is not as optimized when using a struct. The only real difference I see between the both is that you declare `int*` in your struct, but your `auto` variables should be `const int*`. But I already played a bit around with const and it didn't change anything.

Comment: strictly speaking those are SSE not MMX. There is actually a huge architectural different between the two.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherently wrong with your code in either case, and using a different c++ compiler yields different results.

I put each version of your code in a separate function f() and g(), and compiled on a recent g++ (7.2) with -O2 and the results for both versions are literally identical in output.

```
unsigned int f(std::vector<int>& x, std::vector<int>& y, std::vector<int>& z)
{
    auto p=x.data();
    auto q=y.data();
    auto r=z.data();

    unsigned int res = 0;
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<N;++i){
        res+=*p++ + *q++ + *r++;
    }
    return res;
}

unsigned int g(std::vector<int>& x, std::vector<int>& y, std::vector<int>& z)
{
    struct pdata{int *px,*py,*pz;};

    unsigned int res=0;
    pdata d{x.data(),y.data(),z.data()};
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<N;++i){
        res += *d.px++ +*d.py++ +*d.pz++;
    }
    return res;
}
```

And the relevant output:

First, f(), your faster version:

```
f(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&):
  mov r8, QWORD PTR [rdi]
  xor eax, eax
  mov rdi, QWORD PTR [rsi]
  mov rsi, QWORD PTR [rdx]
  xor edx, edx
.L2:
  mov ecx, DWORD PTR [rdi+rdx]
  add ecx, DWORD PTR [r8+rdx]
  add ecx, DWORD PTR [rsi+rdx]
  add rdx, 4
  add eax, ecx
  cmp rdx, 4000000
  jne .L2
  rep ret
```

The version with pointers in the struct incur zero additional overhead:

```
g(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&):
  mov r8, QWORD PTR [rdi]
  xor eax, eax
  mov rdi, QWORD PTR [rsi]
  mov rsi, QWORD PTR [rdx]
  xor edx, edx
.L6:
  mov ecx, DWORD PTR [rdi+rdx]
  add ecx, DWORD PTR [r8+rdx]
  add ecx, DWORD PTR [rsi+rdx]
  add rdx, 4
  add eax, ecx
  cmp rdx, 4000000
  jne .L6
  rep ret
```

You can see for yourself on Godbolt:
https://godbolt.org/g/DBqhDh

So this is an issue with MSVC.  Hopefully it's better on a newer version.

Comment: And on -O3 GCC and clang both use MMX instructions similar to what MSVC uses for the first version.  This is almost certainly programmer cleverness defeating compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

As the poster has pointed out above, the compiler has done some vectorization in the first case. Likely it is having trouble proving, or perhaps didn't try to prove at all, that the pointers for the `std::vector` cannot overlap the struct itself on the stack.

You can try labeling the pointers with the [restrict](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict) qualifier, though I am not sure it is supported in your target environment.

Comment: I've used `__restrict` as per your indication and performance improves a bit but is still well below the `struct`-less case :-(